# Introspection query is run at the wrong url

Tags: aws-lambda, graphql, apollo, serverless-framework, apollo-server

I have a Serverless project with Apollo graphql lambda endpoint at url like:

`https://w040io5bk9.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/graphql`

When I go to it, I get the Playground UI. However, when it runs it's introspection query, it runs it at a wrong url:

`https://w040io5bk9.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/graphql`

Notice the `/dev` is missing.

What sort of misconfiguration might I have done here?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by providing `endpoint` in the `ApolloServer` config:

```
    playground: {
      endpoint: 'graphql'
    }
```

Doesn't make much sense to me either : /